# What is the correct flag when an Answer does not relate to the Question

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I recently flagged two answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332494/why-should-main-be-static) as 'Not an Answer':

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/21406269/2594742
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/21406162/2594742

As the Answers did not relate to the Question in any way.  They talk about JQuery Templateing when the Question is about Why Main is a static in C#.

Both these flags where declined with the reason:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

So what is the correct flag to use when someone posts an Answer which does not relate to the Question?

Comment: Commenting first, and then flagging helps too.

Comment: I already downvoted and flagged again. Any support on downvoting (or flagging) is appreciated since it indicates broader support in the community.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I'm not sure which order I did it in but I commented on both answer in addition to the flags

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Other" and explain **clearly** to the moderators that this is completely irrelevant to the question. I don't believe the moderators can see the *question* the flagged answer is on, without additional clicking. If they therefore come across an *attempted* answer, flagged as NAA, it'll likely be declined.

FWIW, I just custom flagged both of these and used the reason:

> This question is about `public static Main` in C#. ***Nothing*** what-so-ever about jQuery templating. The answer seems to have been posted on the wrong  question completely.

Note that an answer which *tries* to answer the question (no matter how wrong they are) should **not** be flagged this way; instead they should be downvoted (and politely commented). However, these are *clearly* wayward answers, so flagging *is* the way to go here.

Comment: Note: it might be relevant to tell it's the same user who posted two bad answers.

Comment: Hm, it looks like these answers are late answers by a relatively new user. Flagging might actually be a good option here, if only to have the user's recent activity reviewed.

Comment: Interestingly, the user also tried to replace another user's valid answer to that C# question with their irrelevant JavaScript writings. Fortunately, the suggestion was rejected.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: Pfft. That user seems to be struggling to get to grips with the SE system :P.

Comment: Isn't this a case for a comment plus a VLQ-Flag, for "This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed."?

Comment: @Deduplicator: That type of flag is usually reserved for almost-incomprehensible answers, not for answers posted on the wrong question. I wouldn't be surprised if VLQ flags would again by declined in this instance; looking at the answers by themselves (as I said, I'm sure the moderators can't see the question in the mod-queue), these posts look like perfectly valid answers, which *don't* have an content or severe formatting issues.

Comment: @Matt: So, only for formatting, not for content problems?

Comment: I think *content problems* here is for *poor quality content* not *wrong/ wayward content*.

Comment: NAAs go to the LQ queue, anyway, so they probably don't even hit a moderator, do they?

Comment: @Joe: they go into the mod queue as well. Although, having said that, I'm not sure whether flags can be declined via the LQ queue, or are only marked as helpful/ disputed.

Comment: Sure, but aren't they (usually) handled inside the LQ queue?  Or is it just passing a recommendation to the mod that (a day or two later maybe) handles it?

Comment: @Joe: I think it depends. I've seen about 50/50 on my flags being resolved via the LQ queue vs. moderators. I guess it largely depends on your timezone as to how many moderators are around. I'm UTC+1, so usually see all my flags resolved pretty quickly.

Comment: This is all true, except moderators don't see markdown in other flags (that I know of). Just a little nitpick, though. :P

Answer (score 9):

When an answer does not relate to the question, leave a comment explicitly stating so and giving the evidence, and down-vote it for not-useful.

Then, flag it for Very-Low Quality:

> This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

There's no need to bother the mods, and the VLQQ is way shorter than the moderator-only queue anyway, so you even get a faster response.

Comment: @pnuts, does "content problems" not cover this case well.